# Word for theories that cannot be disproven ?

Tags: logic

Is there any word for something which cannot be disproven. E.g. I want to say: "Vedas were written around 10000 BC". This has some proof but not certain, but it cannot be disproven. What should be the one word for this?

Comment: It can be disproven. There was no writing in the world at all 10,000 years ago. And nobody spoke Vedic Sanskrit then, either.

Comment: Was that extra **0** a typo? [The Vedas are a collection of hymns and other religious texts composed in India between about 1500 and 1000 BCE](http://www.ancient.eu/The_Vedas/) Some scientists say that because *string theory* can never be "proved", they don't like to dignify it with the same term they apply to something as "solid" as the theory of evolution. Perhaps ***belief system**?*

Comment: You may use a word like _traditionally_ to mean it is generally accepted without scientific proof: By tradition, King David wrote the book of Psalms.

Comment: To extend what John Lawler and FumbleFingers are saying: the idea that the Vedas were written 10,000 BC (i.e. ~12K before the present time) is in fact **disproven**. The general word for theories which cannot be disproven, e.g. that there's a [teacup orbiting Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_teapot) or that the [Demiurge is really a plate of pasta](http://www.venganza.org/) is ***unfalsifiable***, but as Popper established in the 20th century, such *prima facie* unfalsifiable claims **must** be discarded as worthless (epistemologically) precisely *because* they're unfalsifiable.

Comment: One might  describe such an idea as [*unfalsifiable*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfalsifiable).

Comment: Perhaps related to ***axiom***: something that is not proven but is taken to be true as the basis for further reasoning.

Comment: I think this is the situation where people often say "arguably."  There is inconclusive support for such idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a proposition cannot be proved, nor can it be disproved, then we can say it is untestable.

If you want to say that no one can prove or disprove it, and just want to replace "disproven" you could say:

> "Vedas were written around 10000 BC". This has some proof but not certain, but it cannot be tested.

However, "some proof" is not a correct phrase here. Either there is proof or there isn't. I respectfully suggest "some evidence" is the phrase here.

Perhaps you could say

> There is some evidence that Vedas were written around 10000 BC, but at present this is untestable,

or

> There is some evidence that Vedas were written around 10000 BC, but this hypothesis cannot be tested.

Although, if you are more concerned with the fact that it can't be disproved,

> There is some evidence that Vedas were written around 10000 BC, and nobody can prove otherwise.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely **no** evidence that the Vedas were written 10,000 BC, and plenty of evidence that they weren’t. There is some evidence that there is a typo in the question, and that it should read _1,000 BC_ (a dating which does have some evidence and is within the range generally accepted).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet    This site is about how to express something in English,  not about the truth or falsehood of what is expressed.

Comment: Hence why I noted it in a comment, not in an answer. There is nothing wrong with pointing out a factual inaccuracy in a question, regardless of whether or not it’s central to the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet    Indeed so, you are quite right of course.  .

Answer (score 5):

> "word for something which cannot be disproven"

One might describe such an idea as being [*unfalsifiable*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfalsifiable), although for a non-scientific usage the layman's definition of *theory* [that the OED gives](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/theory)  could even be used.

If the idea has not yet been tested it could be a *speculation*, though you may want something that suggests a little more thought has gone into the idea if it has "has some proof but not certain".

Dictionary.com says a [*hypothesis*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypothesis) is

> "a proposition [...] accepted as highly probable in the light of established facts"

which might fit your example quite well.

Or: ***Conjecture.***